# JavaScript: Random Style Class Using Math.Random()

Tags: html, css, random

I am in a Basic HTML/Javascript class and I cannot figure out how to "modify the following JavaScript so that it picks one of the style classes at random each time it is called." The below code works, but it isn't randomized. Any suggestions would be helpful. Thank you, in advance!

```
<html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<link href="capstone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<script>
function getRandomInt (min, max) 
{
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
var index = getRandomInt(1, 20);

function stylize()
{
  index++;
  if (index > 7) index =1;
  var s = "myStyle" + index;
  var e = document.getElementById("MessageText");
  e.className = s;
  setTimeout("stylize()", 1500);
  return;
}
 </script>
 </head>

 <body onLoad="stylize()">
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
   <tr>
    <td align="center">
     <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="400">
     <div id="MessageText" class="myStyle1">
      Hello World Wide Web!
     <div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </body>

</html>
```

MY CSS PAGE IS:.....

```
.myStyle1 {font-family:Impact; color:black; font-size:100}
.myStyle2 {font-family:Georgia; color:black; font-size:18}
.myStyl31 {font-family:Tahoma; color:black; font-size:24}
.myStyle4 {font-family:Verdana; color:black; font-size:48}
.myStyle5 {font-family:Impact; color:red; font-size:30}
.myStyle6 {font-family:Marlett; color:green; font-size:65}
.myStyle7 {font-family:Arial; color:blue; font-size:46}
.myStyle8 {font-family:Courier Sans MS Bold; color:blue; font-size:60}
.myStyle9 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35}
.myStyle10 {font-family:Arial Italic; color:blue; font-size:10}
.myStyle11 {font-family:Times New Roman; color:blue; font-size:50}
.myStyle12 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:38}
.myStyle13 {font-family:Verdana; color:white; font-size:30}
.myStyle14 {font-family:Marlett; color:blue; font-size:70}
.myStyle15 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:24}
.myStyle16 {font-family:Georgia; color:blue; font-size:24}
.myStyle17 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35}
.myStyle18 {font-family:Georgia; color:black; font-size:12;}
.myStyle19 {font-family:Arial; color:blue; font-size:20;}
.myStyle20 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:55}
```

This seems to not work for me can anyone help.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `var index = getRandomInt(1, 20);`

And then, replace `index++;` with `var index = getRandomInt(1, 20);`.

And if you want to accept more than 7 styles, remove `if (index > 7) index = 1;`.

In this case, it picks a random number each time. In your case, a random number was picked (mostly 1 of `if (index > 7) index = 1;`) and you incremented it each time.

```html
<html>

<head>
<title>HTML and JavaScript</title>
<link href="capstone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<style>
 .myStyle1 {font-family:Impact; color:black; font-size:100} .myStyle2 {font-family:Georgia; color:black; font-size:18} .myStyl31
{font-family:Tahoma; color:black; font-size:24} .myStyle4 {font-family:Verdana; color:black; font-size:48} .myStyle5 {font-family:Impact;
color:red; font-size:30} .myStyle6 {font-family:Marlett; color:green; font-size:65} .myStyle7 {font-family:Arial; color:blue;
font-size:46} .myStyle8 {font-family:Courier Sans MS Bold; color:blue; font-size:60} .myStyle9 {font-family:Impact; color:blue;
font-size:35} .myStyle10 {font-family:Arial Italic; color:blue; font-size:10} .myStyle11 {font-family:Times New Roman; color:blue;
font-size:50} .myStyle12 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue; font-size:38} .myStyle13 {font-family:Verdana; color:white; font-size:30}
.myStyle14 {font-family:Marlett; color:blue; font-size:70} .myStyle15 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:24} .myStyle16
{font-family:Georgia; color:blue; font-size:24} .myStyle17 {font-family:Impact; color:blue; font-size:35} .myStyle18 {font-family:Georgia;
color:black; font-size:12;} .myStyle19 {font-family:Arial; color:blue; font-size:20;} .myStyle20 {font-family:Tahoma; color:blue;
font-size:55}
</style>
<script>
  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }
  

  function stylize() {
    var index = getRandomInt(1, 20);
    var s = "myStyle" + index;
    var e = document.getElementById("MessageText");
    e.className = s;
    setTimeout("stylize()", 1500);
    return;
  }
</script>
 </head>

 <body onLoad="stylize()">
  <table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
   <tr>
    <td align="center">
     <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="400">
     <div id="MessageText" class="myStyle1">
      Hello World Wide Web!
     <div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>

 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried that and still does not work for some reason

Comment: I would use this but I have to use a CSS sheet

Answer (score 0):

**Remark**

You can **shorten** the code as follows

```js
var text = document.getElementById("text");

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function stylize() {
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    var rand = getRandomInt(1, 20);
    text.setAttribute("class", "myStyle" + rand);
  }, 1500);
}

stylize();
```

```css
.myStyle1 {
  font-family: Impact;
  color: black;
  font-size: 100
}

.myStyle2 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: black;
  font-size: 18
}

.myStye3 {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24
}

.myStyle4 {
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: black;
  font-size: 48
}

.myStyle5 {
  font-family: Impact;
  color: red;
  font-size: 30
}

.myStyle6 {
  font-family: Marlett;
  color: green;
  font-size: 65
}

.myStyle7 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 46
}

.myStyle8 {
  font-family: Courier Sans MS Bold;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 60
}

.myStyle9 {
  font-family: Impact;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 35
}

.myStyle10 {
  font-family: Arial Italic;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 10
}

.myStyle11 {
  font-family: Times New Roman;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 50
}

.myStyle12 {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 38
}

.myStyle13 {
  font-family: Verdana;
  color: white;
  font-size: 30
}

.myStyle14 {
  font-family: Marlett;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 70
}

.myStyle15 {
  font-family: Impact;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24
}

.myStyle16 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 24
}

.myStyle17 {
  font-family: Impact;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 35
}

.myStyle18 {
  font-family: Georgia;
  color: black;
  font-size: 12;
}

.myStyle19 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20;
}

.myStyle20 {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 55
}
```

```html
<table align="center" border="1" bordercolor="black">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <font size="3"><b>STYLE CLASS VIEWER</b></font>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center" height="100" width="400">
      <div id="text" class="myStyle1">
        Hello World Wide Web!
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```